# Adding element inside an array ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am a beginner at using Javascript and React. I am working on creating a receipt wherein I have the `productName` and the product price.
It goes like this:

```
const productName ['BREAD','ORANGE JUICE', 'CANDY']
```

and I want to insert the price for each `productName` like

```
BREAD == 6
ORANGE JUICE == 12
CANDY == 0.2
```

or

```
product: {
name: BREAD
price: 6
}
```

I have the picture of the data in my head but I just don't know how to implement it. What is the best practice when doing this?

and when getting the `response.data` of the array.
I need to get the `productPrice` of each `productName` like `response.data[0].productPrice`. Thank you!
*Note:* I have API routes for post and get and I need the `productPrice` on another page that is why I need the price for total amount of the chosen products

*edit*
I am also working with checkboxes, this is the way I get the values of each `productName`

This is my code for handling checked checkboxes

```
  const handleChangeCheckbox = input => event => {
    var value = event.target.value;
    var isChecked = event.target.checked;
    setChecked(current =>
      current.map(obj => {
        if (obj.option === input) {
          if(isChecked){
          return {...obj, chosen:  [...obj.chosen, value ] };
          }else{
            var newArr = obj.chosen;
            var index = newArr.indexOf(event.target.value);
            newArr.splice(index, 1); // 2nd parameter means remove one item only
            return {...obj, chosen: newArr};
          }
        }
        return obj;
      }),
    );
    console.log(checked);
  }
```

This is the code for checking for checked boxes

```
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState([
    { option: 'Product Name',
      chosen: [],
    },
```

and this is how I get the value of the productName from the checkboxes

```
                  <Form >
                    {productName.map((item, index) => (
                      <div key={index} className="mb-3">
                        <Form.Check
                          input value={[item]}
                          id={[item]}
                          type="checkbox"
                          label={`${item}`}
                          onClick={handleChangeCheckbox('productName')}
                          
                        />
                      </div>
                    ))}
                  </Form>
```

Comment: "insert", where? into mongo DB?

Comment: yes I will insert the data to mongoDB

Comment: So, do you want to have it as array of objects?

Comment: I tried doing it like this const products[{name: 'BREAD', price:'6'}]. So if I change my mapping value into item.name, would I still have the price 6 when inserted into the database?